# Deleting all but a few Variables from a Dataset in SPSS

Tags: python, spss

I have have a data set with about 1000 variables. But I want to work on a dataset only with a small subset of these Variables. What are convenient ways to delete all the non needed variables?

Using the `DELETE VARIABLE` command such as

```
DELETE VARIABLES var1 TO var13 var 15 var 17 TO var var35 ...
```

would be quite annoying and error-prone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### *Sample Data*

```
DATA LIST LIST (",") /
make (A18) price (F4) mpg (F2) rep78 (F1) hdroom (COMMA1.1) 
trunk (F2) weight (F4) length (F3) turn (F2)
displ (F3) gratio (COMMA2.2) foreign (F1) .

BEGIN DATA.
AMC Concord,        4099,   , 3, 2.5, 11, 2930, 186, 40, 121, 3.58, 0
AMC Pacer,          4749,   , 3, 3.0, 11, 3350, 173, 40, 258, 2.53, 0
AMC Spirit,         3799,   , 3,  .0, 12, 2640, 168, 35, 121, 3.08, 0
Audi 5000,          9690, 17, 5, 3.0, 15, 2830, 189, 37, 131, 3.20, 1
Audi Fox,           6295, 23, 3, 2.5, 11, 2070, 174, 36,  97, 3.70, 1
BMW 320i,           9735, 25, 4, 2.5, 12, 2650, 177, 34, 121, 3.64, 1
Buick Century,      4816, 20, 3, 4.5, 16, 3250, 196, 40, 196, 2.93, 0
Buick Electra,      7827, 15, 4, 4.0, 20, 4080, 222, 43, 350, 2.41, 0
Buick LeSabre,      5788, 18, 3, 4.0, 21, 3670, 218, 43, 231, 2.73, 0
END DATA.

    DATASET NAME cars.
```

Lets say you want to extract the Variables *make*, *trunk*  and *turn*.

### SAVE FILE (and GET FILE)

If you want to keep the reduced data set for later use the obvious way would be to use the `/KEEP` option in the `SAVE` command.

```
SAVE OUTFILE='cars.sav'
   /KEEP make trunk turn.
```

On the other hand if you want to open an already existing data set with only a subset of variables, you can use the `GET FILE` command with the `/KEEP` option.

### MATCH FILES

This method is usefull if you want to work only temporarily with a reduced dataset without storing it to hard drive.

```
MATCH FILES 
/FILE *
/KEEP make trunk turn.
```

### Python VariableList Class

The Methods above may take some time if you have a really huge data set because they read (and write) all the data. In that case it might be helpfull to manipulate the data dictionary directly using Python. Well, that's what I thought. This is what I tried so far, more or less succesfull.

```
BEGIN PROGRAM PYTHON.
keepList = ["make", "trunk", "turn"]

import spss

spss.StartDataStep()
datasetObj = spss.Dataset('cars')
varListObj = datasetObj.varlist
varList = [var.name.encode('utf8') for var in varListObj]
datasetObj.close()
spss.EndDataStep()
deleteList = [item for item in varList if item not in keepList]
spss.Submit("DELETE VARIABLES %s." % " ".join(deleteList))

END PROGRAM
```

**Note:** This piece of codes only works if your list of to-delete-variables isn't much longer than 100 (This Bug should be fixed in SPSS v23 or higher). Otherwise you have to split the list into seperate pieces. I tried this by replacing the spss.Submit-line with:

```
chunks = 100
for i in xrange(0, len(deleteList), chunks):
   spss.Submit("DELETE VARIABLES %s." % " ".join(deleteList[i:i+chunks]))
```

The problem with this is that even though the program block runs fast on big data sets, it turned out that after this block every execution of commands is slowed down painfully, maybe caused by a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

Faster and simpler, just use the Python logic to build a DELETE VARIABLES command and do SPSS.submit.  Doing a lot of deletes one by one is very inefficient.

Comment: I agree. Therefore I changed the Python code in my solution. But some problems remain: I can't just submit the Delete Variables command if the list of variables is too long. If I submit the delete Variables command for every single variable seperatly with a for loop the whole procedure takes quite a while. So I tried spliting the list into chunks of 100 variables, but then I get the same result as with my first approach: after running the python code every further execution of commands is slowed down.

Comment: The submitted code is supposed to be automatically line-wrapped to the standard SPSS line length limits, but unfortunately a bug on this was introduced in V22.  Fixpack 1 for V22 fixed this.  Alternatively, you can just wrap the lines yourself using the textwrap Python module or use the SpssWrap class in the spssaux2.py module available from the SPSS Community website.

Comment: @JPK thanks for the advice. I will try it out when I'm back from vacation :-)